# Javafxports on Android won't load image due to "Improper call to JPEG library in state 200"

Tags: mobile, javafx, javafxports, gluon

When I run the application with IntelliJ the image is visible but when ported to Android (6.0 & 4.4.2) it isn't. The Image object is instantiated with an URL (website).

Logcat

```
W/linker: /data/app/com.xxxx.xxxx.scan.application.scanner-2/lib/arm/libjavafx_iio.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libjavafx_iio.so"
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Improper call to JPEG library in state 200
//##The error below is thrown at the new Image(url) operation
W/System.err:     at com.xxxx.xxxx.scan.application.scanner.controllers.ProductController.updateImageView(ProductController.java:117)
```

Method that loads the image

```
    private synchronized void updateImageView(ProductEntry product) {
        if (product.getExtraInfo() != null && product.getExtraInfo().size() > 0) {
            ExtraInfo extraInfo = product.getExtraInfo().get(0);
            figLabel.setText(extraInfo.getInfo());
            image = new Image(extraInfo.getUrl());
            imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
            imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
//            imageView.setSmooth(true);
//            imageView.setCache(true);
            imageView.setImage(image);
        }
    }
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://xxxx.xxxx.com:8080/artifactory/plugins-release'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:+"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}

mainClassName = 'com.essers.pxl2016.scan.application.scanner.MainApplication'

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.essers.pxl2016', name: 'scan-server-definition', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT')
    compile(group: 'com.xxxx.xxxx', name: 'client', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4')
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.7'
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = ['com.xxxx.xxxx.scan.**.*']
    }
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'com.xxxx.xxxx.scan.application.scanner'
    }
}

test {
    exclude 'com/xxxx/xxxx/scan/application/scanner/**'
}
```

src/main/resources/java.custom.properties

```
# Solves crash when clicking the menu.
monocle.stackSize=128000
```

Kind regards

Comment: I've just tested loading jpg images from URLs on Android, and it works. Could you share the link of the image that fails? Or at least anything that we can reproduce?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error either for both a Charm and a javafxports project.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't get the error anymore?

Comment: I still have the error in the project that I'm currently working on which is a JavaFX application with the build.gradle from gluonhq with additional configurations of my own.
When I tried to reproduce the error in a new Gluon Mobile project with multiple views and FXML, created with the IntelliJ plugin, it just worked.
When I created a new JavaFX project with the build.gradle from gluonhq.com, it also worked.

Comment: Then you need to isolate what's failing in your project. Maybe it's not related to the jpg image itself, but another different issue.

Comment: The cause of the problem was the size of the image. The application failed to load a 3264x2448 image but succeeded with a 512x384 image. I don't know if this is normal Android behavior or if it is related to javafxports.

Comment: I think that will depend on the image. I've tested successfully now a 3264x2448 [pic](http://i.imgur.com/E7ZDNa6.jpg), but [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Pyramid_Screen_Saver.JPG) fails on Android due to `Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOI markers` (checking with `adb logcat -v threadtime`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem appears to be the file size of the image. The image showed up after reducing the file size.